# How to make 10x10 printf table display consistently in java?

Tags: java, printf

I'm trying to display a 10x10 table of an ArrayList in console using printf.

like this:

```
  930  396  466  242  315  254  217  820  287  216
  595  220   13  494  186  645  309  902  560   56
  797  980  201  301  479  694  509  778  702  360
  253  995  647  725  327  774  861  420   37  753
  948  107  935  867  399  818   73  427  485   70
  575  385  174  400  940  296   76  569  362  732
   21  197  948  421  852  954  640  528  119  659
   96   55  475    5  903  940  299   45  432   79
  352  363  698  873  130  704   89  245   45  288
  646  378  967  179   94  607  261  710  504   20
```

The code works sometimes, however it will randomly make a new line or fail to make one.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This creates an ArrayList of 100 random integers between the values from 1 to 1000

        int listSize = 100;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = createList(listSize);

        displayList(list);

    }
    private static void displayTable(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println();
        for (Integer num : list) {
            if (list.indexOf(num) % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.printf("%n%5d", num);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%5d", num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here are two examples of outputs I've gotten:

```
  969  500   12  256  945  105  402  868  213  658
  909  144  165  217  828  628  395  682  816  199
  769  220  218  958   97  237   36   92  220  712
  332  640  547  893  210  926  868  486  914  307
  740  962  109  745  347  896   74  922  686  593
   26  964  677  321  889  690  956  892  720  915
  631   90  824  338  887  822   49  529  521  841
  504  946  302  253  175  107  765  225    6  101
  747  841  143  642  533  662  143  528  733  209
  377  366  928  511  404
   26  296  946  597  717
```

```
  673  257  970  480  595  936 1000  490  937   45
  156  619  722  237  448  611  266  603   84  421
  719    8  341  720  284  170  885  740  587  686
  182  111  533  268  455  804  494   14  161   38
  612
  612  235  758  366  607  354  591  914  791
  277  426  318  204  692  851  727  654  696    7
  504  801  213  368  834  928  141  951  714  340
  190  325  129  930  923  654  997  903  569  867
  956  736  712  586  560  770  497  875  854  618
  998  281  953  747  828  212  844  314  494  367
```

Comment: Can you use other data structures, like Arrays?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: `if (list.indexOf(num) % 10 == 0) {`

Comment: That `indexOf` call will find the first instance of a number in the list - if there are multiple occurences of a number in the list this is the wrong answer for all but the first occurence. Just use a separate counter for working out the line ends.

Answer (score 0):

As @akuzminykh said, you have an issue with how you deal with your random number index in your array.

To pe precise, this line:
`if (list.indexOf(num) % 10 == 0) {`

Will return the index of the **FIRST** `num` in your array, so if your `num` corresponds to a previous breakline index (in your case, %10), you will have one new line out of nowhere!

Try using a hand made index with your for loop. Or a counter.

Look at your example:

```
  969  500   12  256  945  105  402  868  213  658
  909  144  165  217  828  628  395  682  816  199
  769  220  218  958   97  237   36   92  220  712
  332  640  547  893  210  926  868  486  914  307
  740  962  109  745  347  896   74  922  686  593
   26  964  677  321  889  690  956  892  720  915 <--- Starting with 26
  631   90  824  338  887  822   49  529  521  841
  504  946  302  253  175  107  765  225    6  101
  747  841  143  642  533  662  143  528  733  209
  377  366  928  511  404
   26  296  946  597  717                          <--- Starting with 26
```